# Estimate head-to-head outcome by winrates

Tags: probability

Let's say Fighter 1 winrate is $60\%$ and Fighter 2 winrate is $30\%$. How can we roughly estimate outcome probabilities of their fight just by that info? In other words, how can we rescale those winrates to add up to $100\%$?

Something like $x' = \frac{x} {x + y}$ gives us $33.3\%$ for the second fighter, while intuitively, his win probability should go down since he's facing a stronger than average opponent.

Is there some known approach for situations like this?

Comment: It would probably depend on how you are calculating your percentages. Say Fighter 1 ($F1$) fought $F3$ $10$ times and won $6$. $F2$ fought $F4$ $10$ times and won $3$. You can't directly weigh their winrates against each other because those probabilities are independent of each other. In the event that there is some cross in matches, then we may be able to work something out

Comment: @wjmccann, yes, let's say the field is huge and everyone's fighting everyone evenly and many times. Down below I've linked to the Log5 approach which satisfies me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this [Log5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log5) approach which seems to be good enough for me.

It estimates the probability of A defeating B via the following formula:

$p_{A,B} = \frac{p_A-p_A\times p_B}{p_A+p_B-2\times p_A\times p_B}$

$60\%$ and $30\%$ become $77.(7)\%$ and $22.(2)\%$ which fits my expectations quite nicely.

Comment: I will  upvote this very useful answer, even though link only answers aren't quite good enough. Can you edit to put in s little of the substance? You can copy the mathjax right from wikipedia.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker, done